# Pass data from TodayExtension to app

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to pass data from a `today extension` to an app? (Even when its not currently running). I wish to pass an `array` of objects to the main app and instantiate a `viewController` based on the objects passed from the today extension. I know how to open the app from the extension just not to too sure how to send data to the app.

```
var arrayToBePassed: [MyDataSource]

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var url = ""
        if currentSort == .recent{
            url = "ext://recent"
        }else{
            url = "ext://popular"            
        }
        //HOW DO I PASS arrayToBePassed to my app?
        let myAppUrl = NSURL(string: url)!
        extensionContext?.openURL(myAppUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
            if (!success) {
            }else{

            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few routes you could go down:

• In your app, implement a URL scheme that can quite literally take that array of objects, formatted as some sort of URL parameter. e.g. `myAwesomeApp://objectArray=[these, are, strings]`. You'll have to parse that URL yourself which should be a bit of fun.

• Look into `NSUserDefaults`. You can initialise a 'shared' user defaults object that both your app and your today extension can use, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6) for more info. You could then store your array in here, and access it from the app when opened.

It really depends on what you're trying to do, but from the impression I get, I feel like the first option may be the best answer. I haven't provided any code, just an outline of how I'd go about it - but hopefully that should be enough to get you off to a good start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't think the first option will for work me, the data being passed is not an array of `strings` just an example (I should probably update the question). I'll definitely look into shared user defaults though

Comment: @kye sure, whatever you're doing you'll probably want to convert your array of objects to NSData somehow (you might want to have a look as `NSCoding`). Depending on how much there is to your object array, turning this NSData into a string you can just pass to the URL might even be an option (don't quote me on that).

Answer (score 0):

Sharing of data is achieved through a new concept called “App Groups”. App Groups are allowed to share some data, including files, but it is worth noting that file access needs to be marshalled to avoid concurrent writes and so forth. This can be achieved through NSFileCoordination, but CoreData and NSUserDefaults handle this out of the box.

You can find the detial Steps [here](https://tapadoo.com/2014/sharing-nsuserdefaults-between-your-app-and-a-today-extension-on-ios-8/)